# Explain Traverse[List] implementation in scalaz-seven

Tags: scala, typeclass, traversal, scalaz, applicative

I'm trying to understand the `traverseImpl` implementation in [scalaz-seven](https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz/blob/scalaz-seven/core/src/main/scala/scalaz/std/List.scala#L47):

```
def traverseImpl[F[_], A, B](l: List[A])(f: A => F[B])(implicit F: Applicative[F]) = {
  DList.fromList(l).foldr(F.point(List[B]())) {
     (a, fbs) => F.map2(f(a), fbs)(_ :: _)
  }
}
```

Can someone explain how the `List` interacts with the `Applicative`? Ultimately, I'd like to be able to implement other instances for `Traverse`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

An applicative lets you apply a function in a context to a value in a context. So for instance, you can apply `some((i: Int) => i + 1)` to `some(3)` and get `some(4)`. Let's forget that for now. I'll come back to that later.

List has two representations, it's either `Nil` or `head :: tail`. You may be used to fold over it using `foldLeft` but there is another way to fold over it:

```
def foldr[A, B](l: List[A], acc0: B, f: (A, B) => B): B = l match {
   case Nil => acc0
   case x :: xs => f(x, foldr(xs, acc0, f))
}
```

Given `List(1, 2)` we fold over the list applying the function starting from the right side - even though we really deconstruct the list from the left side!

```
f(1, f(2, Nil))
```

This can be used to compute the length of a list. Given `List(1, 2)`:

```
foldr(List(1, 2), 0, (i: Int, acc: Int) => 1 + acc)
// returns 2
```

This can also be used to *create* another list:

```
foldr[Int, List[Int]](List(1, 2), List[Int](), _ :: _)
//List[Int] = List(1, 2)
```

So given an empty list and the `::` function we were able to create another list. What if our elements are in some *context*? If our context is an applicative then we can still apply our elements and `::` in that context. Continuing with `List(1, 2)` and `Option` as our applicative. We start with `some(List[Int]()))` we want to apply the `::` function in the `Option` context. This is what the `F.map2` does. It takes two values in their `Option` context, put the provided function of two arguments into the `Option` context and apply them together.

So outside the context we have `(2, Nil) => 2 :: Nil`

In context we have: `(Some(2), Some(Nil)) => Some(2 :: Nil)`

Going back to the original question:

```
// do a foldr 
DList.fromList(l).foldr(F.point(List[B]())) {
  // starting with an empty list in its applicative context F.point(List[B]())
  (a, fbs) => F.map2(f(a), fbs)(_ :: _)
  // Apply the `::` function to the two values in the context
}
```

I am not sure why the difference `DList` is used. What I see is that it uses trampolines so hopefully that makes this implementation work without blowing the stack, but I have not tried so I don't know.

The interesting part about implementing the right fold like this is that I think it gives you an approach to implement traverse for algebric data types using [catamorphisms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catamorphism).

For instance given:

```
trait Tree[+A]
object Leaf extends Tree[Nothing]
case class Node[A](a: A, left: Tree[A], right: Tree[A]) extends Tree[A]
```

Fold would be defined like this (which is really following the same approach as for `List`):

```
def fold[A, B](tree: Tree[A], valueForLeaf: B, functionForNode: (A, B, B) => B): B = {
  tree match {
    case Leaf => valueForLeaf
    case Node(a, left, right) => functionForNode(a, 
        fold(left, valueForLeaf, functionForNode), 
        fold(right, valueForLeaf, functionForNode)
      )
  }
}
```

And traverse would use that `fold` with `F.point(Leaf)` and apply it to `Node.apply`. Though there is no `F.map3` so it may be a bit cumbersome.

Comment: awesome answer that does not require any external knowledge

Answer (score 6):

This not something so easy to grasp. I recommend reading the article linked at the beginning of [my blog post on the subject](http://etorreborre.blogspot.com.au/2011/06/essence-of-iterator-pattern.html).

I also did a presentation on the subject during the last Functional Programming meeting in Sydney and you can find the slides [here](http://code.ouroborus.net/fp-syd/past/2012/2012-02-torreborre-iterator-pattern.pptx).

If I can try to explain in a few words, `traverse` is going to traverse each element of the list one by one, eventually re-constructing the list `(_ :: _)` but accumulating/executing some kind of "effects" as given by the `F Applicative`. If `F` is `State` it keeps track of some state. If `F` is the applicative corresponding to a `Monoid` it aggregates some kind of measure for each element of the list.

The main interaction of the list and the applicative is with the `map2` application where it receives a `F[B]` element and attach it to the other `F[List[B]]` elements by definition of `F` as an `Applicative` and the use of the `List` constructor `::` as the specific function to apply.

From there you see that implementing other instances of `Traverse` is only about `apply`ing the data constructors of the data structure you want to traverse. If you have a look at the linked powerpoint presentation, you'll see some slides with a binary tree traversal.

Comment: indeed, both your blog article and your slides are helpful!

Comment: Great slides ! Could you make a pdf out of it ? I got some annoying issues with fonts and alignment.

Comment: I uploaded the pdf slides here: http://www.slideshare.net/etorreborre/the-essence-of-the-iterator-pattern-pdf

Answer (score 2):

`List#foldRight` blows the stack for large lists. Try this in a REPL:

```
List.range(0, 10000).foldRight(())((a, b) => ())
```

Typically, you can reverse the list, use `foldLeft`, then reverse the result to avoid this problem. But with `traverse` we really have to process the elements in the correct order, to make sure that the effect is treated correctly. `DList` is a convenient way to do this, by virtue of trampolining.

In the end, these tests must pass:

https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz/blob/scalaz-seven/tests/src/test/scala/scalaz/TraverseTest.scala#L13
https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz/blob/scalaz-seven/tests/src/test/scala/scalaz/std/ListTest.scala#L11
https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz/blob/scalaz-seven/core/src/main/scala/scalaz/Traverse.scala#L76